# Even if I own 51% of stake (or have 51% computational power) and try to cheat, can't others still see that my block is invalid?

Tags: security, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, validators

I'm thinking about how proof of stake works exactly.

As I understand, here is how it is secure:

- I cannot forge a tx where random A pays me X amount because I would need the private keys of A. Validators can easily see that A did not sign this tx.
- I cannot validate my invalid tx myself because I would need to be a validator.
- I cannot be a validator without depositing a stake and getting selected by other validators randomly.
- I cannot forge a staking tx (deposit a stake) because validators can see I do not have enough ETH.
- If I am a legitimate validator, I cannot fake-validate an invalid tx/block because other validators will mark that same tx/block as invalid and see that I did the opposite and penalise me by taking some of my stake.

#### My question is:

**Even if I have 51% stake which means my vote of validation outweighs all other validators, why can't "non-validator normal nodes" (i.e. wallets who are consuming and not publishing blocks) simply check my invalid block that I've just published and see that it's invalid?** At the end of the day, every tx still needs to have valid signatures and I cannot spend more than what I own.

In fact, I could ask the same question about PoW. Even if I have computational power to calculate the next hash quicker than everyone else, any node on the network can still check the validity of my block.

### Potential answer:

In, PoW, it's super easy for wallets to calculate just one hash and see if it matches the header in the new invalid block. That is enough and we do not need to inspect every tx in the block because we know that header hash requires work to be derived (it's a solution to the "target" and nonce incrementing puzzle) so we simply trust PoW i.e. **PoW is vulnerable to 51% attacks by design**.

However, in PoS, that "puzzle" isn't part of the algo, there is no "mining" and it's easy for anyone to publish a fake block so a non-validator node would have to check every tx in the block which is a lot more work. I don't know how deep it has to go, maybe all the way back to the start of the chain.

Could it be that in PoS it's too costly for non-validator nodes to check every block themselves so by-design they do not do so and trust the published block just like in PoW? meaning it's vulnerable to 51% attacks as well (stake this time not computational power)?

Comment: The reason PoW is vulnerable to 51% attacks is mostly due to possible double-spends; the transactions are all valid as individual transactions, but not when there are multiple transactions spending the same assets. Now, I'm not sure how this differs in PoS

Comment: I was thinking of that, but how can you spend more than your balance anyway? Also, please upvote the question if you're interested in finding the answer too.

Comment: _PoW is vulnerable to 51% attacks by design_ you got is right. The 51% attak is `defined` , so it can happen and will happen. The security of a billion dollar market is holding on the premise that there won't be any other more computationally strong chain.

Comment: The PoS is giving authority to validators and is trusting that validators won't become corrupt (or hacked). So the PoS is holding on the premise that validators always will be "good guys".

Comment: However the solution to 51% attack exists, I actually have it designed already. I am probably the only person in the world who is holding the solution. Keep trying and maybe you will find it too.